# SQL Server : update table set using subquery - The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a set of records in a table with values from within results of a subquery. When I run this query, I get error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 75
> The multi-part identifier `be_prsn.prsn_id` could not be bound.

Code:

```
UPDATE be_org 
SET org_id = 322 
WHERE be_prsn.prsn_id IN (SELECT prsn.prsn_id 
                          FROM be_prsn prsn
                          JOIN be_mbr mbr ON mbr.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
                          JOIN be_empt_hist empt ON empt.mbr_id = mbr.mbr_id
                          LEFT JOIN be_org org ON empt.org_id = org.org_id
                          OUTER APPLY
                              (SELECT 
                                   acct.acct_id, pln.pln_sys_cd, 
                                   COUNT(pyrl.pyrl_id) AS NumPyrl
                               FROM 
                                   be_mbr_acct acct
                               JOIN
                                   be_pstn_hist pstn ON acct.pln_id = pstn.pln_id
                               JOIN
                                   be_pln pln ON acct.pln_id = pln.pln_id
                               LEFT JOIN 
                                   be_pyrl pyrl ON pyrl.pstn_hist_id = pstn.pstn_hist_id
                               WHERE 
                                   acct.mbr_id = mbr.mbr_id
                                   AND pstn.empt_hist_id = empt.empt_hist_id
                                   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM be_cntrb cntrb
                                               WHERE cntrb.pyrl_id = pyrl.pyrl_id
                                                 AND cntrb.rvrs_in = 0)
                               GROUP BY
                                   acct.acct_id, pln.pln_sys_cd) acct
                          WHERE 
                              prsn.prsn_id = 7286);
```

Answer (score 0):

You update attribute `org_id` of table `be_org`. So actually an attribute from another table `be_prsn` (I assume that's what you want to express) isn't meaningful in this context. If you wanted to include another table in your `where`-condition, you would have to join that other table with `be_org`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The joins are as follows. I'm trying to update be_org.org_id where prsn.prsn_id = 7286.

be_prsn prsn > be_mbr mbr
be_mbr mbr > be_empt_hist empt
be_empt_hist empt > be_org org

Comment: Your joins are in the subquery and don't pertain to your main UPDATE statement. The problem is in lines 1 and 3. You update `be_org`, but your WHERE condition is on `be_prsn`, and these two aren't joined.

Answer (score 0):

you have **be_prsn** alias in where's nested select and use  `be_prsn.prsn_id` on parent level. there you have only `be_org`
You should do join

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... the joins are as follows. I can't do a direct join between be_prsn and be_org directly.

                          FROM be_prsn prsn
                          JOIN be_mbr mbr ON mbr.prsn_id = prsn.prsn_id
                          JOIN be_empt_hist empt ON empt.mbr_id = mbr.mbr_id
                          LEFT JOIN be_org org ON empt.org_id = org.org_id